# How to get proper response in angular 11

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I am watching a series of tutorials.
I am using a Firebase for my Database. Picture below is my code for getting a list of data from my database. But unfortunately I got an error as picture below.

I also tried to change the type of my response into `any`

```
 .subscribe((response: any) => {
```

but upon fetching my data it throws an error says `ERROR TypeError: response.json is not a function`

[image]

[image]

BTW I am running `"@angular/cli": "~11.0.1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do the trick.

```
getRecipe() {
   this.http.get<Recipe[]>(/*YOUR API CALL*/)
      .subscribe((recipes: Recipe[]) => this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes));
}
```

You can already know what return type your expecting from your API call by adding it inbetween the `< >`. The JSON will automatically be cast into your classes.

As @Waseem Rakab pointed out, it's not necessary to have `response.json` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to call the json method (also it’s not available in angular) since angular handles this for you and returns the correct type.